# Is there a way to remove a resource group depending on tags with Runbook/automation script?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

I have a runbook PowerShell that deletes ALL resource groups and everything on them but with the name of the RG. Is there a way to do the same but only with tags that are associate to that RG? Instead of asking me for a NAMEFILTER PARAMETER when running the runbook, it could ask for the TAG? I have been looking everywhere but I can't find a way to delete a resource group by tag without including/using the name.

Comment: If any of suggested answers did help you out consider marking them as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very dangerous to run scripts like this but it's like this

```
Get-AzResourceGroup -Tag @{ TagName="TagValue" } | Remove-AzResourceGroup
```

Test this locally first and later add -force parameter to remove without prompt

In case of older modules you might need to run AzureRM alias

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag @{ TagName="TagValue" } | Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

To get resource groups that have a specific tag, use:

`(Get-AzResourceGroup -Tag @{ Dept="Finance" }).ResourceGroupName`

Once you have the list of RG names that have the tag you want to delete, you can they loop through them to delete.